# C++ type `Int` distinct from `int` (maybe yacc/bison?)

Tags: c++, yacc

C++ is case-sensitive. The standard (short) integer is named `int`. So if my application is using type `Int` (starts upper-case) that must be different(?) Is `INT` different again?

The application is a compiler. I'm looking at its parsing, which uses a typical yacc setup. Consider [`input.c` here](https://github.com/FranklinChen/hugs98-plus-Sep2006/blob/master/src/input.c). Line 206/207 declares the current read position, char and lookahead char. (See comment lines 186 ff.)

```
static Int    row, column, startColumn;
static int    c0, c1;
```

What does the upper-case `Int` mean? And where do I find its `typedef`? I've looked in `#include "machdep.h", "char.h", "storage.h"` (all in the same github repo). But `#include <ctype.h>` I can't find in the repo, nor the application's installation on my machine -- is it in the bowels of the C++ compiler?

(I can supply a lot more info about this application if you need it -- ask away in the comments. I figured better to keep the q short to start with.)

**Edit/response:** Thank you everybody for the quick and accurate responses in the Comments. @dratenik "having symbols that differ in letter case only is a sure-fire recipe for terrible headaches." Indeed. Headache was what it was giving me, so I'm glad I asked.

Comment: My guess is that it's defined in the same place as `List`. I doubt very much it's in the C++ compiler or in the C++ standard library.

Comment: "_The standard (short) integer is named `int`_" - The standard short integer is named `short int`.

Comment: Defined here see https://github.com/FranklinChen/hugs98-plus-Sep2006/blob/54ab69bd6313adbbed1d790b46aca2a0305ea67e/src/prelude.h#L695 `typedef int      Int;`

Comment: For the meaning of `#include` using angle brackets `<>`, see [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: If you want to find out where something is defined, define an incompatible symbol with the same name. The compiler error should tell you where the other one is.

Comment: On a more general note, having symbols that differ in letter case only is a sure-fire recipe for terrible headaches.

Comment: Code-spelunking tip: things like fundamental types are often defined in the first included header.